# What functions satisfy $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,y)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x,y)dx$?

Tags: functional-equations, integral-equations

What functions satisfy $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,y)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x,y)dx$ for all $y\in \mathbb{R}$? Under what conditions would this imply that $f(x,y)=g(x,y)$?

Comment: What sort of conditions are you supposing $f,g$ satisfy (for instance, they are clearly integrable in some sense)? What is your own gut feeling? How would you justify that gut feeling?

Comment: Generally this is very hard, any odd, integrable function of $x$ times an integrable function of $y$ will give $0$, so $g$ just needs to be in the integral $0$ subspace of $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ where here we treat $g$ purely as a function of $x$ with $y$ held constant, and this is still a very "big" subspace.

$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} 0 & |x|\le1\\ {\sin x\over x^2(y^2+1)} & |x|>1\end{cases}$$

Comment: @user161825 I would like them to satisfy the weakest possible conditions say just integrability and continuity. My gut feeling is that in general they should be equal because after integration we land up with a function of just $y$ and these must be equal.

Comment: @AdamHughes What happens if I make the additional restriction that there are $y_1$ and $y_2$ such that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,y_1)dx \neq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,y_2)dx$? Also you said in your comment that "Generally this is hard..." does this mean that you don't think there are some "simple" conditions that will make $f(x,y)=g(x,y)$?

Comment: A simple condition that ensures equality of the functions is $f\geq g$.

Comment: @user103828 Continuity is not enough, you can replace my first coordinate with $$f(x,y)={\sin(x)\over 1+y^2}, \; |x|\le 1$$

Comment: What about $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,y_1)dx \neq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,y_2)dx$ for some $y_1$ and $y_2$? This is to avoid separating the functions.

Comment: It seems to me like there should exist some relevant statement about continuous probability distributions that would be helpful, wherein we assume $\iint_{\Bbb R^2} f = \iint_{\Bbb R^2} g = 1$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom This is exactly the type of condition I would be happy with... but why would the assumption $\int \int f =\int \int g$ lead to $f=g$?

Comment: @user161825 That makes sense but it would be hard to incorporate in the problem that I am working with. Are there any other simple conditions that you can think of? (I am looking for something like Omnomnomnom suggested).

Comment: @user103828 it wouldn't.  In fact, assuming $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,y)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x,y)dx$ for all $y$ automatically gives us $\iint f = \iint g$.  It's just that if we normalize the functions so that $\iint f = \iint g = 1$, $f$ and $g$ are not just functions, but also probability densities.